# add fields to a node mapped to date input.The fields value should be mapped to date value

Tags: 7, entities

I want to add  fields to the a content type.

The user should be able input text values that are mapped to a particular date.

**Ex: for july 1,** 
a particular field can have a value of **145, for july 13** it can have a value of **155** and so on.

The date can be entered using **date popup field** and for every date the field can have different value.

I need the values for **30 dates**. The fields are multiple.

I have 5 fields and all 5 fields have different values for a particular day.

I explored the **conditional_fields** module but it doesn’t seem to meet the requirement.

Comment: Any hints how it can be solved?